# Ajax inserted content not accessible in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a pure jquery/js site, mostly to practice some jquery. I am using a load statement to load a menu from a file of common html, like so:

```
$('#categoryListing').load('../common.html #categoryLinksUL');
```

which loads:

```
<ul id="categoryLinksUL">
          <li><a href="#anklets" rel="ajax">Anklets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#bracelets" rel="ajax">Bracelets</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is where I am using it now I need to alter the href of the above links, but they are not part of the dom. In previous instances I was able to use .live(click... But not here. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Specifically I need to load the links and change the href from #anklets to ?category=anklets

Comment: What do you mean with they are not part of the DOM? You say that the list is loaded, so they should be. Or is it *supposed* to load this content? Can you see the list?

Comment: The list loads and I can see it. But when I do 'this:$('#categoryLinksUL li a').each(function() {', categoryLinksUL is empty. I manually added the list into the html and categoryLinksUL is not empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about the following?

```
$('#categoryListing').load('../common.html #categoryLinksUL', function() {
    $('li a[href^="#"']').each(function () {
        this.href = '?category=' + this.href.substr(1);
    });
});
```

In my example, after the load is completed, the anonymous function is called. It takes every anchor with a hash HREF and replaces it with an HREF based on your description.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dimitry, you solution basically worked. I finally used:

```
$('#categoryListing').load('../common.html #categoryLinksUL', function() {
  $('#categoryListing li a').each(function () {
    var hashPos=this.href.indexOf("#");
    var tCategory = this.href.substr(hashPos+1,this.href.length );
  });
});
```

So why did jQuery recognize categoryListing there? I tried moving the each function outside of the load function and categoryListing did not contain any links. Is it because maybe the load was not completed when it tried to get categoryListing links? Seems like that is possible.

Thanks,
        Todd

Comment: The anonymous function is called once your loaded HTML is added to the DOM. If you called the anonymous function just after the load() function, then you would still not have the HTML on the page.